# Is self-signed SSL server cert compatible with described architecture?

Tags: tls, web-application, cryptography, certificate-authority, tcp

I'm creating an application with a client-server architecture using SSL via TCP. Clients can authorize themselves on the server using login and password and become users. Only users can perform any actions with their accounts. Unauthorized clients can only authorize themselves.

Now clients only with my client app using my server, but I think it will be ok if somebody will use third-party app.

As I understood, now only my server authorize itself for the each client, so each client know that this is a real server. Server test command:

> openssl s_server -key server.key -cert server.crt -accept 1678

On the client side I have only `.der` certificate.

So, the questions:

1. Is this understanding correct?
2. Do I also need a client side keys for clients authorizations on the server, or this is enough for described architecture?
3. Do I need a CA cerificate or self-signed certificate will be the same?

Comment: Your descriptions of the architecture is very vague. Within this vague description both self-signed certificates would be enough and client certificates would not be needed. But, if you would add more clear security and usability requirements to the description it might be possible that this might rule out self-signed certificates and might need client certificates. Since this detail is missing I propose to close the question as too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your comment. Can you say which exactly details I need provide for more specific question?

Comment: As for self-signed: do you have an app and use certificate pinning or is it acceptable for the client to explicitly override the warning coming with self-signed certificates, of course after explicitly checking the fingerprint? As for client-certificate: do you need more security as provided by username+password or not? And how will the client certificate be created and distributed?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich as for self-signed: yes, I have an app and after your comment I will use certificate pinning, thanks. But unfortunately I don't understand what you meant in this sentence: _"or is it acceptable for the client to explicitly override the warning coming with self-signed certificates, of course after explicitly checking the fingerprint"_, can you explain? As for client-certificate: I think no, if client knows username and pass, then it will be enough to authorize him. I think if I need it, then it will be created on the server and it will be distributed within package of the app.

Comment: The part you don't understand is only relevant if you use a browser based app and not a "native" app. And if username and password is sufficient authentication then you don't need client certificates.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ok, many thanks! So: client certificates are not needed, certificate pinning with self-signed certificates will be enough. Correct me if something is wrong.

Comment: yes, sounds good.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ok, now I tried to test certificate pinning on the iOS and Android: I manually installed .crt #1 on the phone(so, now it is trusted), after that I tried to connect client and server using this(#1) certificate, and client has been connected. Next server used certificate #1, and client used #2, but connection was failed(as it needed for cert pinning). And at the last, server and client used certificate #2 and connection was established. So, after this test can we say that I using correct certificate pinning?

Comment: Given that  all of these certificates are self-signed and the results you got from your tests it sounds properly setup.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it's nice to hear it, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, in the usual TLS/SSL case, only the server authenticates itself to the client and not the other way round. To create trust for this authentication on the client side, you need to store either the server certificate itself (or its fingerprint) or a list of certificates from trusted certification authorities.
2. Since you are describing, that your users authenticate themselves via username and password, TLS client authentication is not neccesary. You could replace your user authentication with it or augment the security of your system by using both schemes but you can live without it.
3. You do not need a certificate signed by a public CA. If you are using a self signed certificate you need to store it in your client application and provide it to all third-party-client vendors. You have to take care though, if you plan or need to rollover the server's certificate, since that will become more complicated without using a trusted issuer certificate (You cannot just switch to a new certificate signed by the trusted CA but have to create the new self-signed some time before using it, include it into the trust store of your app and wait till all your users have updated).

Comment: A better approach is to create your own CA (Certificate Authority) *root* certificate with a long expiry and load the public key for that into all client computers certificate stores. Then you can roll over your operating certs without having to revisit every client PC. You **MUST** keep the CA root cert absolutely secure though of course.

Comment: Here is a script that correctly creates root and server certs. https://github.com/TotallyInformation/SelfSigned-Cert-Creator

Comment: @Julian Knight:  I have to disagree. Rolling you own CA is not really a good idea, unless you really know, what you are doing.

Comment: That's why I wrote a script to do it properly in a consistent way. ;-) It can actually be a LOT more secure than using 3rd party CA's. Also, I'd much rather encourage people to use certs properly than not and not everyone can afford a decent cert (the free ones all have limitations). Using a self-signed root cert is a great way to minimise management of the certs without loosing security when you can't afford a 3rd party cert.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer! Almost all is clear, except this sentence: _"You have to take care though, if you plan or need to rollover the server's certificate, since that will become more complicated without using a trusted issuer certificate."_. Can you explain this?

Comment: @don-prog I have extended my answer.

Comment: Ok, now I think everything is clear, thanks one more time.

Comment: @JulianKnight many thanks for your tool. But I have a few question about it: I can convert chain.pem and my-private-root-ca.crt from the client dir to .bks and use them on Android, but in the .der format for iOS I can convert only chain.pem. What file I should use on the client side and for what we need another files in the client dir?Unfortunately it's not clear for me after your readme. Also, I using privkey.pem and cert.pem on the server, is it correct? And the last question: I can't use certificates on iOS emulator using local ip, but I can use 127.0.0.1, is it ok and why does this happen?

Comment: Probably best to take this to the issues log on GitHub so we can look at what you need and see if we can do anything.